# New user password aborted (passwd)

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is it possible to change a password after not initially setting one?

Below states `password unchanged`, but from what? Is it initialized with a random value?

```
Enter new UNIX username: user1
New password:
Retype new password:
Sorry, passwords do not match.
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
Try again? [y/N] N

Installation successful!
To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
See "man sudo_root" for details.

Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage
```

Comment: "in hopes to be able to change the user name..." Once entered, it is not easy to change user name, though a link to a new user name can be made. Easier to start over, recreating Ubuntu.